# Wordpress wp_title () function not working for Yootheme template with Warp Framework

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, blogs

I am using a Yootheme template for my wordpress site http://sribasu.com
The theme is built on Warp Framework. My theme's head.php file prints page title after concatinating bloginfo name and wp_title ().

Unfortunately, the wp_title () function is not generating any output. As a result all my inner pages and blog post pages are having same title as homepage. Is there any issue with warp framework when using this function?

I am using wordpress 3.6. I have been trying to search google to see if it's a common issue or not. But didn't find a working solution yet. Please help.

Edit:
The Code for head.php (**/yoo_revista_wp/warp/systems/wordpress/layouts/head.php**) is as follows:

```
<meta charset="<?php bloginfo('charset'); ?>" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<?php if($this['config']->get('responsive', false)): ?>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<?php endif; ?>
<title><?php bloginfo('name'); ?> <?php wp_title(); ?></title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?php echo $this['path']->url('template:favicon.ico');?>" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="<?php echo $this['path']->url('template:apple_touch_icon.png'); ?>" />
<?php

wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
wp_head();

// set body classes
$this['config']->set('body_classes', implode(' ', get_body_class($this['config']->get('body_classes'))));

// get styles and scripts
$styles  = $this['asset']->get('css');
$scripts = $this['asset']->get('js');

// compress styles and scripts
if ($compression = $this['config']->get('compression')) {

    $options = array();
    $filters = array('CSSImportResolver', 'CSSRewriteURL', 'CSSCompressor');

    // set options
    if ($compression == 3) {
        $options['Gzip'] = true;
    }

    // set filter
    if ($compression >= 2 && ($this['useragent']->browser() != 'msie' || version_compare($this['useragent']->version(), '8.0', '>='))) {
        $filters[] = 'CSSImageBase64';
    }

    if ($styles) {
        // cache styles and check for remote styles
        $styles = array($this['asset']->cache('template.css', $styles, $filters, $options));
        foreach ($styles[0] as $style) {
            if ($style->getType() == 'File' && !$style->getPath()) {
                $styles[] = $style;
            }
        }
    }

    if ($scripts) {
        // cache scripts and check for remote scripts
        $scripts = array($this['asset']->cache('template.js', $scripts, array('JSCompressor'), $options));
        foreach ($scripts[0] as $script) {
            if ($script->getType() == 'File' && !$script->getPath()) {
                $scripts[] = $script;
            }
        }
    }

}

// add styles
if ($styles) {
    foreach ($styles as $style) {
        if ($url = $style->getUrl()) {
            printf("<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"%s\" />\n", $url);
        } else {
            printf("<style>%s</style>\n", $style->getContent());
        }
    }
}

// add scripts
if ($scripts) {
    foreach ($scripts as $script) {
        if ($url = $script->getUrl()) {
            printf("<script src=\"%s\"></script>\n", $url);
        } else {
            printf("<script>%s</script>\n", $script->getContent());
        }
    }
}

// add feed link
if (strlen($this['config']->get('rss_url',''))) {
    printf("<link href=\"%s\" rel=\"alternate\" type=\"application/rss+xml\" title=\"RSS 2.0\" />\n", $this['config']->get('rss_url'));
}

$this->output('head');
```

Comment: We need code to debug that... code you refer to.

Comment: @BenRacicot many thanks for responding... Added the code in the question above..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got wonderful clue from Ben's response, I must admit. Finally identified the culprit Plugin - it is Contus Video Gallery. The plugin is good in what it does, but tampered my page titles :X

I fixed the wp_title filter function in the Contus Video Gallery plugin in **/plugins/contus-video-gallery/hdflvvideoshare.php** and it worked like a charm!

#### Previously the code was:

```
function add_video_title() {
    global $wpdb;
    $videoID            = url_to_custompostid(get_permalink());
    if (isset($_GET['p'])) {
        $videoID        = intval($_GET['p']);
    }
    if (isset($_GET['playid'])) {
        $playId         = intval($_GET['playid']);
    }
    if (!empty($videoID)) {
        $videoID        = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT vid FROM " . $wpdb->prefix . "hdflvvideoshare WHERE slug='" . intval($videoID) . "'");
        $video_title    = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT t1.name"
                        . " FROM " . $wpdb->prefix . "hdflvvideoshare AS t1"
                        . " WHERE t1.publish='1' AND t1.vid='" . intval($videoID) . "' LIMIT 1");
    }
    if (!empty($playId)) {
        $video_title    = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT t1.playlist_name AS name"
                        . " FROM " . $wpdb->prefix . "hdflvvideoshare_playlist AS t1"
                        . " WHERE t1.is_publish='1' AND t1.pid='" . intval($playId) . "' LIMIT 1");
    }
    if (!empty($video_title))
        echo $video_title;
}
```

#### Now the code is:

```
function add_video_title($title) {
    if($_REQUEST['post_type']!='videogallery'){
        return $title;
    }
    global $wpdb;
    $videoID            = url_to_custompostid(get_permalink());
    if (isset($_GET['p'])) {
        $videoID        = intval($_GET['p']);
    }
    if (isset($_GET['playid'])) {
        $playId         = intval($_GET['playid']);
    }
    if (!empty($videoID)) {
        $videoID        = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT vid FROM " . $wpdb->prefix . "hdflvvideoshare WHERE slug='" . intval($videoID) . "'");
        $video_title    = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT t1.name"
                        . " FROM " . $wpdb->prefix . "hdflvvideoshare AS t1"
                        . " WHERE t1.publish='1' AND t1.vid='" . intval($videoID) . "' LIMIT 1");
    }
    if (!empty($playId)) {
        $video_title    = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT t1.playlist_name AS name"
                        . " FROM " . $wpdb->prefix . "hdflvvideoshare_playlist AS t1"
                        . " WHERE t1.is_publish='1' AND t1.pid='" . intval($playId) . "' LIMIT 1");
    }
    if (!empty($video_title))
        return $video_title;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_title):

> The wp_title() function should not be used by a theme in conjunction
>   with other strings or functions (like concatenating with
>   bloginfo('name')) to write the content of the  element, because
>   it will render plugins unable to rewrite the whole title in case the
>   plugins use the wp_title filter do the rewrite, which is the best
>   practice. The use of this function is now a requirement for theme
>   developers.

TESTED CODE:

```
<?php bloginfo('name'); ?><?php wp_title('&raquo;'); ?>
```

The first parameter, $sep: Text to display before or after (specified by $seplocation) the post title (i.e. the separator).
Default: » (»)

Comment: Ben, thanks again. Will you please suggest a working code, which can be used to display page title in **BLOG NAME >> PAGE TITLE** format? I do have number of Active plugins in my blog. So, you think, some of them are using wp_title filter?

Comment: Hmm, they may be, that's all. Wanna list them? I will write up that code in 1 minute.